# Why does GCC -O3 cause infinite std::distance with filter iterators over a std::deque?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, deque, filter-iterator

After much pain and misery, I've tracked down some very odd behaviour where `std::distance` never returns when given a range of `boost::filter_iterator`s over a `std::deque`. It appears the problem is unique to GCC (6.1+) with `-O3` optimisations. Here is an example demonstrating the offending behaviour:

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

struct Foo
{
    std::string bar, s = "";
    char a = '\0';
};

int main()
{
    const std::deque<Foo> foos(14, {""});
    const std::string test {};
    const auto p = [test] (const auto& foo) { return foo.bar == test; };
    using boost::make_filter_iterator;
    const auto begin = make_filter_iterator(p, std::cbegin(foos), std::cend(foos));
    const auto end   = make_filter_iterator(p, std::cend(foos), std::cend(foos));
    std::cout << std::distance(begin, end) << std::endl;
}
```

Some observations:

- GCC with optimisations `-O2` or less returns as expected.
- Clang (3.8) returns the correct answer with any optimisation level.
- Changing `std::deque` to `std::vector` or `std::list` results in expected behaviour.
- The `14` is critical; anything less and the problem disappears.
- The `sizeof(Foo)` is important; removing `s` or `a` makes the problem go away.
- Capturing `test` by reference, or just comparing to a constant expression (e.g. `foo.bar == " "`) results in normal behaviour.
- There are no compiler warnings (with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).
- Valgrind reports no errors.
- Use `fsanitize=undefined` and the problem goes away.

What's going on?

Comment: Which version of boost are you using

Comment: Also what platform are you on? (i686? x86_84?)

Comment: @M.M x86_64. The problem is also reproducible on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f8670dfa6e21ec2). Not sure what system they are using.

Comment: Something going wrong in SLP1 (vectorization) apparently...

Comment: I think you could report it to gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: Tested a bit, changing `Foo` size and amount of elements. It seems that problem arises when there enough elements to fill two internal blocks in deque. I would say that it is a either GCC bug or a problem with libstdc++ deque implementation.

Comment: [Bug reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77550). Will post as answer once confirmed.

Comment: @Daniel: in case some reminders are helpful! Did you have any updates on this, as per your above comment, and did the late answer below help at all?

Comment: @halfer Daniel gave a link to the bug report, where you can see that this was fixed in late September (with a backport to gcc-6 one month later).

Comment: Thanks @MarcGlisse, most helpful. I was however wondering if Daniel might make an answer here, or accept the existing one, if the question set out above is resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour was due to a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77550) caused by bad vectorisation optimisation. A fix has now been issued, which should appear in GCC 6.3.

For those stuck with GCC 5.4 - 6.2, the compiler option `-fno-tree-slp-vectorize` will 'fix' the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think that these findings below may be useful for both improve the bug report and also for using in your code to workaround the problem.

By debugging the optimized output and playing with optimization flags and with minor code changes I've reached the conclusion about the specific optimization flags that are causing the error.

The set of options are:

```
-O -fno-auto-inc-dec -fno-branch-count-reg -fno-combine-stack-adjustments -fno-compare-elim -fno-cprop-registers -fno-dce -fno-defer-pop -fno-delayed-branch -fno-dse -fno-forward-propagate -fno-guess-branch-probability -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-if-conversion -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fno-ipa-pure-const -fno-ipa-profile -fno-ipa-reference -fno-merge-constants -fno-move-loop-invariants -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-shrink-wrap -fno-split-wide-types -fno-ssa-backprop -fno-ssa-phiopt -fno-tree-bit-ccp -fno-tree-ccp -fno-tree-ch -fno-tree-coalesce-vars -fno-tree-phiprop -fno-tree-sink -fno-tree-slsr -fno-tree-dse -fno-tree-forwprop -fno-tree-fre -fno-unit-at-a-time -fno-tree-ter -fno-tree-sra -fno-tree-copy-prop -fstrict-aliasing -ftree-slp-vectorize -std=c++14
```

Sorry for that long set but what I actually wanted was something like: `-O0 -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-pta -ftree-dce -fstrict-aliasing -ftree-slp-vectorize` (I've tried with -Og also) plus the magic steps of O1...

Note that just `-O3 -f-no-tree-slp-vectorize` will already fix the behavior, but by using the full options I've sent the debugging is almost easy...

Furthermore, it looks like the existence of the operator `==(string, string)` is generating the confusion in the compiler.

If you examine the code pasted bellow where all the commented by #if 0 code, when activated works in the place of the original code, you may find the problem where I didn't.

Note that the `==()` operator is not even called because the `foo.a != '\0'` is always true in the test. Therefore it looks like it's existence is making the compiler to generate the bad code.

Note also that any of the commented code inside the loop also changing the behavior to the expected one and that's why I suspected of the vectorization flags for starters.

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>
#include <string.h>

struct Foo
{
    std::string bar, s = "";
    char a = 'n';
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& f)
{
    os << f.bar << '/' << f.a;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::deque<Foo> foos(14, {"abc"});
    const std::string test {"abc"};
    Foo other;
    other.bar = "last"; other.a = 'l';
    foos.push_back(other);
    other.bar = "first";
    other.a = 'f';
    foos.push_front(other);
    //
#if 0
    const auto p = [test] (const auto& foo) { return foo.a != '\0'; };
#elif 0
    const auto p = [test] (const auto& foo) {
        bool  rc =  (foo.a != '\0');
        if (!rc)
            rc = (foo.bar == std::string(test));
        return rc;
    };
#elif 1
    const auto p = [test] (const auto& foo) {
        bool  rc =  (foo.a != '\0');
        if (!rc)
            rc = (foo.bar == test);
        return rc;
    };
#endif
    using boost::make_filter_iterator;
    const auto begin = make_filter_iterator(p, std::cbegin(foos), std::cend(foos));
    const auto end   = make_filter_iterator(p, std::cend(foos), std::cend(foos));
    std::cout << std::distance(end, end) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::distance(begin, begin) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::distance(std::cbegin(foos), std::cend(foos)) << std::endl;

    auto __first = begin;
    auto __last = end;

    int __n = 0;
    //std::cout << __last << std::endl;
    //std::deque<char> trace;
    //Foo trace[21];
    const int max = foos.size();
    char trace[max+5]; memset(trace, 'c', sizeof(trace));

    std::cout << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << *__last << std::endl;

    while (__first != __last)
    {
        trace[__n] = (*__first).a;
        //trace[__n] = (*__first);
        //trace.push_back((*__first).a);
        //std::cout << *__first << std::endl;
        ++__n;
        ++__first;
        if (__n > max + 5)
            break;
        //std::cout << __n << std::endl;
        //std::cout << (__first != __last) << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto f: trace)
        std::cout << f  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Tadaaaaa: " <<  __n << std::endl;

    //std::cout << std::distance(begin, end) << std::endl;

}
```